# How to define traits that statically guarantee that an object and one of its fields both share a same label

Tags: scala, types, singleton, traits, path-dependent-type

**Question:**

Consider a simple ADT `T = A | B`, i.e.

```
sealed trait T
case object A extends T
case object B extends T
```

and classes `Inner` and `Outer` both with a label in `T`, such that `Outer` contains an `Inner`.

```
trait Inner {
  val label: T
}

trait Outer {
  val label: T
  val i: Inner
}
```

I would like to statically enforce that the `Inner` inside the `Outer` both have the same label. What would be the/a idiomatic approach to enact such guarantee in Scala?

---

**My attempt:**

Via inclusion of the types as fields and corresponding refinements.

```
trait Inner {
  type Label <: T
  val label: Label
}

trait Outer { self =>
  type Label <: T
  val label: Label
  val i: Inner {type Label = self.Label}
}
```

It does work to an extent, in that given `Inner` objects with `A` and `B`,

```
object IA extends Inner {
  override type Label = A.type
  override val label: A.type = A
}

object IB extends Inner {
  override type Label = B.type
  override val label: B.type = B
}
```

an `Outer` with an `A` can only take `IA` but not `IB`.

```
object OA extends Outer {
  override type Label = A.type
  override val label: A.type = A
  override val i: Inner{type Label = A.type} = IA
}
```

There's at least two shortcomings though.

1) This logic is not enforced by the `Inner` and `Outer` traits. The object must have a concrete label value `A` or `B`, but its type rather than `A.type` or `B.type` can be the wider `T`.

```
object I2A extends Inner {
  override type Label = T
  override val label: T = A
}

object O2B extends Outer {
  override type Label = T
  override val label: T = B
  override val i: Inner{type Label = T} = I2A
}
```

2) since labels should be singleton objects it would be nice if it were possible to summon the value from the type. i.e., something like:

```
trait Inner {
  type Label <: T
  val label: ??? // summon the single value for the singleton of type Label
}

trait Outer { self =>
  type Label <: T
  val label: ??? // summon the single value for the singleton of type Label
  val i: Inner {type Label = self.Label}
}
```

but the first shortcoming already shows this to be impossible since the `Label` can be wider than `A.type` and `B.type`.

Comment: Can you make `Inner` and `Outer` parametrized? For example: `trait Inner[TI <: T]` ?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik that could work. I was trying without parameters first, since it'd involve less changes in the existing code base, I would expect. But a solution with parameterised traits would do too.

Comment: I think parametrized would work as suggested by @Krzysztof Atłasik . `trait Inner[A <: T]{val label: A}`. `trait Outer[A] {
  val label: A;
  val i: Inner[A]
}`